# Getting Automation error when opening website

Tags: vba

Hey im getting "Automation error" on my VBA code:

```
Set Doc = IE.document
```

when i debug i get the above as the culprit, when i mouse over Doc is empty, and IE.document is throwing the automation error

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True

    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.document


    Dim Np As String

    For line = 2 To lp

        ipp = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(line, 1).Value

        If ipp <> "" Then

            IE.navigate ipp

            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

            Np = Doc.getElementsByName("TITLE")(0).innerText


        End If
        IE.Quit
    Next line


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you load a new page you need to refresh the reference to the newly-loaded document:

```
Set Doc = IE.document
```

...right after the `Do` loop